# Converting pennies in to change

Tags: java

I am learning Java and am making code that converts the number of pennies in to change when entered.

One thing I need to change is my output so that if there is only one coin it prints solely as 20p rather than 1*20p.

I would also appreciate if anyone notes any other improvements that could be made.

Thanks :)

```
class Main { 
public static void main( String args[] ) {

    System.out.print("#Please enter the amount of change : ");
    int change = BIO.getInt();

    while(change > 0)
    {
        int twopounds, pounds, fifty, twenty, ten, five, two, one;

        twopounds = change / 200;
        int left = change % 200;

        pounds = left / 100;
        left = left % 100;

        fifty = left / 50;
        left = left % 50;

        twenty = left / 20;
        left = left % 20;

        ten = left / 10;
        left = left % 10;

        five = left / 5;
        left = left % 5;

        two = left / 2;

        one = left / 1;

        int nbCoins = twopounds + pounds + fifty + twenty + ten + five + two + one;

        if (change == 1)
        {
            System.out.print("1 coin" + "\n");
        }

        if (change > 500)
        { 
            System.out.print("Invalid amount " + change + "p" + "\n");
        }

        if (change <= 500 && change > 1)

            System.out.print(change + "p " + nbCoins +" coins ");

        {

            if ( twopounds > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( twopounds > 0 ? twopounds + "*200p " : "" );
            }

            if ( pounds > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( pounds > 0 ? pounds + "*100p " : "" );
            }

            if ( fifty > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( fifty > 0 ? fifty + "*50p " : "" );
            }

            if ( twenty > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( twenty > 0 ? twenty + "*20p " : "" );
            }

            if ( ten > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( ten > 0 ? ten + "*10p " : "" );
            }

            if ( five > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( five > 0 ? five + "*5p " : "" );
            }

            if ( two > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( two > 0 ? two + "*2p " : "" );
            }

            if ( one > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( one > 0 ? one + "*1p " : "" );
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print("#Please enter the amount of change : ");
        change = BIO.getInt();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Use a [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)! Don't reinvent the wheel - specifically look at the [choice format](http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=17191&tstart=0) options.

Comment: You should post this on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It's off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DaoWen there are still bugs / new features / changes in functionality that need to be addressed. That would make it off topic on codereview and on topic here.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is define your coins as emums,
ie:

```
enum Coin {
    twopounds(200), pounds(100), fifty(50), twenty(20), ten(10), five(5), two(
            2), one(1);
    int value;

    Coin(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    int getCoins(int amount){
        return amount/value;
    }
    int getReminder(int amount){
        return amount%value;
    }
}
```

then you could do

```
int change  = 321;
    for (Coin coin : Coin.values()){
        int count = coin.getCoins(change );
        if (count!=0){
            System.out.println(coin.name()+" : " +count);
        }
        change  = coin.getReminder(change );
    }
```

and that will prints you your change in coins,
you could take this further, and define your wallet where you hold all your money
ie

```
 class Wallet{
     int money;
     int getAllCoins(Coin coin){
         int coins = coin.getCoins(money);
         money=coin.getReminder(money);
         return coins;
     }
 }
```

but this will be overkill for this simple scenario

Answer (score -1):

You don't want entries with 1 coin to be displayed as 1*value so replace the comparison

```
 System.out.print( twopounds > 0 ? twopounds + "*200p " : " " );
```

to

```
 System.out.print( twopounds > 1 ? twopounds + "*200p " : "200p " );
```

in other words, you compare the `numberOfCoins` to one, if it's just one coin, then write just the `value` of the coin. Else write `numberOfCoins * value`

Replace the relevant part of your code with this:

```
            if ( twopounds > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( twopounds > 1 ? twopounds + "*200p " : "200p " );
            }

            if ( pounds > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( pounds > 1 ? pounds + "*100p " : "100p " );
            }

            if ( fifty > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( fifty > 1 ? fifty + "*50p " : "50p " );
            }

            if ( twenty > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( twenty > 1 ? twenty + "*20p " : "20p " );
            }

            if ( ten > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( ten > 1 ? ten + "*10p " : "10p " );
            }

            if ( five > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( five > 1 ? five + "*5p " : "5p " );
            }

            if ( two > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( two > 1 ? two + "*2p " : "2p " );
            }

            if ( one > 0 )
            {
                System.out.print( one > 1 ? one + "*1p " : "1p " );
            }
```

Comment: You've got a bunch of code here, but you don't tell us why it would work to fix the issue at hand.

Comment: I'll repeat what I said above. Don't reinvent the wheel, use a `MessageFormat`. This is horrible.

Comment: @Makoto i think it's pretty straightforward. what is there to explain.

Comment: Well, I'll put it like this.  Explain why your solution is ideal in a way that everyone can both understand and agree with.  Those who've seen and read code before might be able to understand your approach, but it doesn't really explain your approach very well.

Comment: @BoristheSpider i agree, but the op has posted multiple posts about this same problem (or homework i guess). he might need this particular solution even though there are multiple better ways to do it. I tried to provide a fix for his code, not rewrite his assignment.

Comment: Up-voted because there is very little code that "everyone can [...] agree with"